# Memory to memory variables only create reference, but its not working with delete - Solidity 0.5.0

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.5.x

Learning Solidity latest version 0.5.0. And having bit confusion about data location rules.

It says that,

> Assignments from memory to memory only create references. This means
>   that changes to one memory variable are also visible in all other
>   memory variables that refer to the same data.

I'm trying to understand it with an example

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Locations {

    function doSomething() public pure returns (uint[] memory) {

    uint[] memory localMemoryArray1 = new uint[](3);
    localMemoryArray1[0] = 4;
    localMemoryArray1[1] = 5;
    localMemoryArray1[2] = 6;

    uint[] memory localMemoryArray2 = localMemoryArray1;
    delete localMemoryArray1; 
    return localMemoryArray2;
  }
}
```

However, this returns value `4,5,6`. As it is a reference type, it should return `0,0,0`. Not sure if its my misunderstanding.

Further changes as per following code works as doc stated

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Locations {

    function doSomething() public pure returns (uint[] memory) {

    uint[] memory localMemoryArray1 = new uint[](3);
    localMemoryArray1[0] = 4;
    localMemoryArray1[1] = 5;
    localMemoryArray1[2] = 6;

    uint[] memory localMemoryArray2 = localMemoryArray1;
    localMemoryArray1[0] = 10; //<==== assigning new value
    return localMemoryArray2;
  }
}
```

Above code returns `10,5,6`, which is right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your second example, you should be able to deduce that `delete` only sets a value to zero, and doesn't delete a memory block or an array (as you're mistakenly expecting, out of  your experience in "traditional" systems).

So `delete localMemoryArray1` doesn't yield the effect that you're expecting to see.

Change it to:

```
delete localMemoryArray1[0]
delete localMemoryArray1[1]
delete localMemoryArray1[2]
```

And you'll see that your function returns an array of 3 zeros.